# Python - too many values to unpack at line 10

Tags: python, list, filter, tuples

In the below code, I'm trying to filter the fruits that cost more than 1.00..

```
fruits = [
   ( 'apple',  0.99 ),
   ( 'orange', 1.25 ),
   ( 'pear',   1.49 ),
   ( 'banana', 0.75 ),
]

def preferred(fruit):
    pfruit = [ (x, y) for (x, y) in fruit if y > 1 ]
    return pfruit

favorites = filter(preferred, fruits)
print favorites
```

I get an error saying :

> ValueError: too many values to unpack at line 10

Comment: you are mixing `filter` and list comprehension (which do the same thing in this case) you either need to do `favorites = preferred(fruits)` or make `preferred` return just True or False based on the condition for one single fruit.

Comment: @cricket_007 filter takes a callable as the first argument, the OP is passing `preferred` which is a callable as the first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Simply call the method without the `filter`

```
>>> preferred(fruits)
# [('orange', 1.25), ('pear', 1.49)]
```

Option 2: Use `filter` in some way with a callable

```
fruits = [
    ( 'apple',  0.99 ),
    ( 'orange', 1.25 ),
    ( 'pear',   1.49 ),
    ( 'banana', 0.75 ),
]

filter(lambda fruit: fruit[1] > 1.0, fruits)
# [('orange', 1.25), ('pear', 1.49)]
```

Option 2.5: Rewrite the `preferred` function to return `True`/`False` for a *single* fruit.

```
def preferred(fruit):
    return fruit[1] > 1

filter(preferred, fruits)
# [('orange', 1.25), ('pear', 1.49)]
```

Comment: `filter` does not need to take a lambda, `preferred` could easily be modified in the OP code to return the comparison for *each* fruit in the list instead of *all* of them

Comment: Thanks much. I was mixing two different animals.

Comment: @cricket_007. Sorry Cricket. I'm new to this. Thank you for you help